# Retrieve non-abstract class property value from abstract class variable

Tags: c#, abstract-class

I have a library where ModelElement is an abstract class and ModelBeam and ModelShell are classes inherited from ModelElement. ModelShell specifically have a propriety called "mesh" and it's value is a Mesh class. I wonder how I can retrieve the Mesh from a ModelElement variable after checking that the variable is a ModelShell object.

I wish something like the code above:

```
foreach (ModelElement elem in model.elems)
{
    if (elem.GetType() == typeof(ModelBeam))
    {
       conect.Add(elem._node_inds);
    }
    if (elem.GetType() == typeof(ModelShell))
    {
        Mesh mesh = elem.mesh;
        foreach (Mesh m in mesh)
        {
           conect.Add(m._node_inds);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doing a cast might help you: `Mesh mesh = ((Mesh)elem).mesh`

Comment: search for visitor pattern

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `is` keyword and then a direct cast:

```
if (elem is ModelShell)
{
    var modelShell = (ModelShell)elem;
    foreach (var m in modelShell.mesh)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

If the `elem` isn't `ModelShell` this will return false and never enter the if block.

Alternatively, you can use the `as` keyword. This one performs a cast if you casting using a correct type or else results in `null`. So after casting you need to check if the variable is `null` or not.

```
var modelShell = elem as ModelShell;
if (modelShell != null)
{
    foreach (var m in modelShell.mesh)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this ..

```
if(elem instanceof ModelBeam){

}else if(elem instanceof ModelShell){

}
```

Comment: That was Java? The question is in C#?

Comment: sorry ... didn't notice !!

Comment: Also, simply for the type was already done by the OP. The problem they had was simply to cast it in a safe manner,

Answer (score 0):

Try following code. Basically, using operator **[is](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw.aspx)** and casting to ModelShell should work.

```
foreach (ModelElement elem in model.elems)
    {
        if (elem is ModelBeam)
        {
            conect.Add(elem._node_inds);
        }
        if (elem is ModelShell)
        {
    Mesh mesh = ((ModelShell)elem).mesh;
            foreach (Mesh m in mesh)
            {
                conect.Add(m._node_inds);
            }
        }
    }
```